# How to make multiple locations open the same index.html file in nginx?

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config, nginx-location

I am developing a website (html/css/js, no php involved). Due to requirements, I use a docker container with an nginx image inside.

I have two HTML files that are the same. One should open as root (e.g. `www.example.com`) and the other one should open when the subdir subdirectory is hit (e.g. `www.example.com/subdir`).

I do not want to have the same file copied multiple times due to obvious reasons.

In nginx, how can I make the `www.example.com` automatically redirect to `www.example.com/subdir` or vice versa (the `www.example.com/subdir` redirect to `www.example.com`)?

I tried various things but I keep receiving 403 forbidden.

Comment: Do you want to serve the same file under `www.example.com` and `www.example.com/subdir` or do you want to redirect a user to the other? That's a slight difference. Also if you get 403 forbidden you should have a look inside the nginx logs and look for the file that nginx want's to access.

Comment: Can you explain to me what is the difference between the two because I am not very into this topic?
Also, nginx gives the following error in the logs: `30#30: *8 directory index of "/usr/share/nginx/html/" is forbidden` when I hit `www.example.com`. Now I have one copy of the file located in `/usr/share/nginx/html/subdir/index.html`.

Comment: A redirect means you redirect the user somewhere else. So e.g. he accesses `www.example.com` and you send a redirect to `www.example.com/subdir`, then the browser receives the redirect and sends a new request to the givin url. In the link bar of the user will then be the `www.example.com/subdir`. If you just serve the same content, the user sends the request and gets the content and its done. So where is your `index.html` located, that you might want to serve from both locations? Or is it the `/usr/share/nginx/html/subdir/index.html` file?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense thank you. So, I would prefer to serve the same html file for both locations. My index.html is currently inside `/usr/share/nginx/html/subdir/`

In `/usr/share/nginx/html/`, I only have the `subdir` directory where all my content is, nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so the following solution should work for you:

```
location = / {     # Serving that index.html file when requesting / (root)
  index /subdir/index.html;
}

location /subdir {    # Serve that subdirectory how you want, e.g. like that
  root /var/www/html;
  index index.html;
}
```